# Split a 3D number array into number of small arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to split a image array (band x width x height) into N smaller arrays and store the small arrays in one numpy array as (N x band x width/N x height/N)

For example,  if band = 4, width = 16 and height = 16, input array is of shape 4x16x16. say, N=4  then  I want to split my input array into four small arrays and store it in one output array of shape say 4x4x4x4. If shape of the input array is  not divisible by N, then I want to reshape the input array first so its width and height is divisible by N and then do the split.

Comment: so you actually want to rearrange your array?  Have a look at `np.reshape`. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html. If you need more help, let us know

Comment: No that's not what I want. I want to split the big array into small array

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you want N arrays of shape `(N, band, width/N, height/N)`. how is it different from reshaping into `(N, N, band, width/N, height/N)`?

Comment: Yes, but then you want to construct an array out of the small arrays. If you're only interested in the reconstructed array then reshaping is what you want

Comment: Oh yes I get it now. It is reshaping. How do I deal with cases where Width is not divisible by N?